# ERROR Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `${item}-${index}`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-native, key

I keep getting this error 'ERROR  Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `${item}-${index}`' and don't know why? How can I go about fixing it? Please help thank you in advance!

```
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList 
                data={tabs}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => '${item}-${index}'}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pill} onPress={() => { setSelectedTab(item); }}>
                            <Text style={styles.pillText}>{item}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                }}
            />
    
            <LinearGradient colors={['gold', '#FF7F50', '#FF7F50']} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Main Menu Screen</Text>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{ address }</Text>
            </LinearGradient>
        </View>
        );
    };
```

> Error:
> ERROR  Warning: Encountered two children with the same key,
> `${item}-${index}`.

Comment: Hi, could you add the piece of code ?

Comment: Either you're using the same `item`/`index` combination for different properties or you're using `${item}-${index}` as a key for multiple properties. Don't do this.

Comment: Sorry, i was editing the question.

Comment: `'${item}-${index}'` contains the string `${item}-${index}`. The placeholders aren't replaced. You need back ticks to create a template literal `\`${item}-${index}\``. This is either a typo or a duplicate.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: I wrote it in my previous comment. There is the actual code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Or how do I fix the error?

Comment: So I need to remove strings, my friend?

Comment: Replace `'${item}-${index}'` with 
`\`${item}-${index}\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace '' by `` around `${item}-${index}` in order to interpolate your variables in the string. But in fact you only need to refer to the index as follows :

```
return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList 
                data={tabs}
                keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pill} onPress={() => { setSelectedTab(item); }}>
                            <Text style={styles.pillText}>{item}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                }}
            />
    
            <LinearGradient colors={['gold', '#FF7F50', '#FF7F50']} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Main Menu Screen</Text>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{ address }</Text>
            </LinearGradient>
        </View>
        );
    };
```

Comment: Using index as key has significant down sides, using a compound key protects against some of these even if the cost is some extra rendering.

Comment: So am getting no error but for some reason, the data is not showing up on the page.

Comment: data={tabs} is not showing on the page

Comment: @pilchard You're right using Index as a key is an anti-pattern but it's like other anti-pattern that don't have a real alternative 90% of the time. I'm not comfortable with compound for the reasons you mention. Imo using stable ID should be the right way, but if you don't have it...

Comment: What's in your `tabs` ?